# How can I know which child has exited in C?

Tags: c, fork

i have 3 child that end at different times in different order each time, but i dont know how to get which end first

i have something like this, where "winner", "second" and "third" are, random generated times, the first ending is "winner" but i dont know who it is

```
    wait(&winner);
wait(&second);
wait(&third);
printf("======================================\n");
printf("----------Classification---------------\n");
printf("======================================\n");
printf("-First-.... Team %d , time: %d\n",/*1*/, WEXITSTATUS(winner));
printf("-Second-.... Team %d , time: %d\n",/*2*/, WEXITSTATUS(second));
printf("-Third-.... Team %d , time: %d\n",/*3*/, WEXITSTATUS(third));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should read the man page of [wait(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html). It returns the `pid_t` of the waited process.

You may also want to use `waitpid` (with `W_NOHANG` if you don't want to really wait in a blocking manner).

Also, read [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html). You could handle `SIGCHLD` ....

And [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) has several chapters related to the issue.

Comment: Thank, you, work fine whit waitpid and a comparation function